# i am working on Struts2 and hibernate integration. it shows an error unable to instantiate the action in namespace. how can i resolve it

Tags: hibernate, struts2

i cant insert the values its showing that could not instantiate action in namespace '/null'

my pojo class where i declare the model for the variables and creates the table

```
package com.konzern.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity

@Table(name = "register")

public class Register implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

 @Column(name = "UserId")

private int UserId;

 @Column(name = "UserName")

 private String UserName;

 @Column(name = "Designation")
 private String Designation;

 @Column(name = "DOJ")
 private String DOJ;

 @Column(name = "DOB")
 private String DOB;



 @Column(name = "Address")
 private String Address;

 @Column(name = "Phone")
 private String Phone;

 @Column(name = "Blood")
 private String Blood;

 @Column(name = "Email")
 private String Email;

 @Column(name = "EmpPassword")
 private String EmpPassword;

public int getUserId() {
    return UserId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    UserId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return Designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    Designation = designation;
}

public String getDOJ() {
    return DOJ;
}

public void setDOJ(String dOJ) {
    DOJ = dOJ;
}

public String getDOB() {
    return DOB;
}

public void setDOB(String dOB) {
    DOB = dOB;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

public String getBlood() {
    return Blood;
}

public void setBlood(String blood) {
    Blood = blood;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getEmpPassword() {
    return EmpPassword;
}

public void setEmpPassword(String empPassword) {
    EmpPassword = empPassword;
}


}
```

controller class where i get the values from the jsp page

```
package com.konzern.controller;


import java.net.URL;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ApplicationAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.mapping.Map;

import com.konzern.operations.RegisterOperations;
import com.konzern.pojo.Login;
import com.konzern.pojo.Register;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RegisterController  extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware,ApplicationAware {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     RegisterOperations ro=new RegisterOperations();

     Register r;

     public Register getR(){
         return r;
     }

     public void setR(Register r){
         this.r=r;

     }
     Login l;

     public Login getL() {
        return l;
    }

    public void setL(Login l) {
        this.l = l;
    }
    HttpServletRequest request;
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.request=request;

    }
      public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
            return request;
        }    

      Map m;
        public void setApplication(Map m)
        {
            this.m=m;
        }

      public String insertaction(){
          System.out.println("hhhhhh");
          ro.registration(r);
          ro.insert(l);
          return SUCCESS;

      }

     /* public String tolog(){
          System.out.println("hhhhhh");
          ro.insert(l);
          return SUCCESS;

      }*/

    @Override
    public void setApplication(java.util.Map<String, Object> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

struts.xml

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

        <struts>
            <include file="struts-default.xml"/>




            <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
                value="ApplicationResources" />

            <package name="a" extends="struts-default">

          <!--   <interceptors>
                    <interceptor class="com.konzern.loginInterceptor" name="loginInterceptor"/>
                    <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
                        <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
                        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
                    </interceptor-stack>                 
                </interceptors>      -->

               <!--  <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>

                <global-results>  
                    <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>                        
                </global-results> --> 

                <action name="verify" class="com.konzern.controller.LoginController" method="LoginAction">
                  <result name="success">/Newlogin.jsp</result>
                </action>
                 <action name="login" class="com.konzern.controller.LoginController" method="indexAction">
                      <result name="success">/Admin.jsp</result>
                      <result name="login">/User.jsp</result>
                    <result name="error">/Newlogin.jsp</result>
                </action> 
                <action name="logout" class="com.konzern.controller.LoginController" method="logoutAction">
                  <result name="success">/Newlogin.jsp</result>
                </action>
                <action name="myjobs" class="com.konzern.controller.LoginController" method="LoginAction">
                <result name="success">/Attendance.jsp</result>
                </action>
                 <action name="Register" class="com.konzern.controller.RegisterController" method="insertaction">
                <result name="success">/Newlogin.jsp</result>
                </action>


            </package>
        </struts>

        stack trace:
```

type Exception report

```
        message Unable to instantiate Action, com.konzern.controller.RegisterController, defined for 'Register' in namespace '/'null

        description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

        exception

        Unable to instantiate Action, com.konzern.controller.RegisterController,  defined for 'Register' in namespace '/'null
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:316)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
            org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
            org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
        root cause

        java.lang.NullPointerException
            com.konzern.operations.RegisterOperations.<init>(RegisterOperations.java:17)
            com.konzern.controller.RegisterController.<init>(RegisterController.java:27)
            sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
            java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:182)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
            org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
            org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
            com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

login.jsp

```
> <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> <%@ page
> import="java.util.*;" %>
> 
> <html>
> 
> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Konzern</title> <link
> href="style/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> </head>
> 
> <body> <div class="header_full">
>       <div class="header">
>           <div class="Logo_holder"></div>            
>           </div> </div> <!--HEADER ENDS HERE-->
> 
> <div class="current_username_full">   <div
> class="current_username_holder">Log In</div> </div>
> 
> <!--USERNAME ENDS HERE-->
> 
> <div class="options_holder_full">     <div class="options_holder">
>       <div class="log_in_holder">
>           <div class="ADMIN_login">
>               <s:form action="login">
>           <h1>Log in here</h1>
>                 <label></label>
>             
>                 <s:textfield label="Username" name="b.userid" cssClass="inputforlogin"/>
>                 <br></br>
>                 <s:password label="Password" name="b.password" cssClass="inputforlogin"/>
>                
>                <s:submit value="login" cssClass="button" />
>                 
>                 
>                 </s:form>
>                 <p style="float:left; margin-top:2px; margin-left:120px;"><a href="Register.jsp">Register here</a></p>
>             </div>          
>         </div>
>     </div> </div> <!--OPTIONS_HOLDER_FULL-->
> 
> <div class="footer_full"></div>
> 
> 
> </body> </html>
```

register.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> <%@ page
> import="java.util.*;" %> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <title>Konzern</title> <link href="style/css.css" rel="stylesheet"
> type="text/css"> </head>
> 
> <body> <div class="header_full">
>       <div class="header">
>           <div class="Logo_holder"></div>            
>           </div> </div> <!--HEADER ENDS HERE-->
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> <div class="current_username_full">   <div
> class="current_username_holder">Register new user</div> </div>
> 
> <!--USERNAME ENDS HERE-->
> 
> 
> 
> <div class="options_holder_full">     <div class="options_holder">
>       <div class="register_holder">
>           <div class="register">
>               <h1>Register here</h1>
>               <s:form action="Register">
>               
>               <s:textfield name="r.UserName" label="Name" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.Designation" label="Designation" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.DOJ" label="Date of Join" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.DOB" label="Date of Birth/Age" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textarea  name="r.Address" label="Address" cssClass="textarea"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.Phone" label="Mobile Number" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.Blood" label="Blood Group" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.Email" label="E-mail" cssClass="input"/>
>               <s:textfield name="r.EmpPassword" label="Password" cssClass="input"/>
>               
>               <s:submit value="Register" cssClass="button" />
>             
>               </s:form>
>             
> 
>             </div>
>             
>         </div>
>     </div> </div> <!--OPTIONS_HOLDER_FULL-->
> 
> <div class="footer_full"></div>
> 
> 
> </body> </html>
```

Comment: This question is unclear, also you should simplify the code.

Comment: i am posting for first time. sorry, i dont know the pattern to post here. Please check the stack trace and tell me why this error occurs

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you in this area, I just comment to suggest you to edit the question to become more attractive to awnwerers, questions must demostrate your effort and must have a clear description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the registercontroller class as it is showing an exception in that class.

1. Try removing the register action from struts.xml and check whether all other action classes are working.

   **Or**
2. Post the jsp file.

   **Or**
3. You could try getting the register class object using model driven
   method.

change your class to implement model driven interface like below.

```
public class RegisterController  extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware,ApplicationAware,ModelDriven{}
```

and intialize the register class like below in the first line of your class.

```
Register r = new Register();
```

and then finally implement the getModel method in your class like

```
public Object getModel() {
    return r;
}
```

Comment: @user3358910 
actually it is showing an exception in 27 th line of register controller class and in 17 th line of register operations class.Check on those to lines or post those two lines.

Comment: @user3358910 
i think it's the problem with getting values from register page in controller class in register class object r as it is showing null pointer exception.try using model driven method to solve this..[Check this link](http://www.developer.am/documentation/struts2/?page=struts-2-modeldriven-example)

Comment: thank you i used the model driven method and its working